# How to save mongodb collections in an array? while using mongoose with expressJS?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, typescript

I want to save collections from a MongoDB database into an array, so it can be like an array of JavaScript objects.

Comment: sharing some of your code helps people find the problem. Also, please take some time to read the how to ask a good question guide. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

mongodb way: `db.collectionName.find().toArray()`

consider toskv comment for an better answer